# How to count all accounts for the same user

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a data for all users and their account, I need to count all accounts that has the same user,
what ive tried is something like :

```
select column 1 , column 2 , count(name) from mytable 
group by  column 1 , column 2;
```

but its giving me :
[image: sql]

So, what I really need is counting all accounts that has the same name.

For example:
First account is 3, > because it belongs to one person, and so on.

Comment: How do you suppose we could help you if we neither know what your table looks like nor what identifies two users to be the "same user"? Please provide a table structure, sample data, expected results and what you have tried to achieve those results. Your above shown query is invalid BTW ...

Answer (score 1):

From your explanation,
I understand; You are looking for output in below format :

```
account_name    number_of_accounts
First Account   3
Second Account  2
Third Account   1
```

This can be achieved with following query in Oracle.

```
SELECT account_name, COUNT(DISTINCT account_number) AS number_of_accounts
FROM mytable
GROUP BY account_name
ORDER BY number_of_accounts desc;
```

Here is [a demo using SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8891d/3)

This shall give you the expected output :

```
    account_name    number_of_accounts
    First Account   3
    Second Account  2
    Third Account   1
```

Please replace your actual column names in above query.